# *** Error compiling './__MACOSX/._request.py' [Google Cloud]

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-functions, httprequest, gcloud

I'm trying to use Cloud Function in gcloud but i get this error

```
Build failed: *** Error compiling './__MACOSX/._request.py'...
```

and i cannot understand why I'm getting this. (btw I'm very new to gcloud)

And the code i deployed was this >

```
import requests
from datetime import date
import base64
from google.cloud import storage
import json


def create_json(json_object, filename):
    '''
    this function will create json object in
    google cloud storage
    '''
    # create a blob
    blob = BUCKET.blob("raw_data/"+filename)
    # upload the blob 
    blob.upload_from_string(
        data=json.dumps(json_object),
        content_type='application/json'
        )
    result = filename + ' upload complete'
    return {'response' : type(result)}

def main():
      url = "xxx"

      payload={}

      headers = {
      'authority': 'xxx',
      'accept': '*/*',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.7',
      'cookie': 'xxx',
      'if-none-match': '"c9a5-KeIG0gepOCXKYXsEiIlXvqNwGh4"',
      'referer': 'https://sa.aqar.fm/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/1',
      'sec-ch-ua': 'xxx',
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': 'xx',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"xx"',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      'sec-gpc': '1',
      'sentry-trace': 'xxx',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
      }

      response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
      today = date.today()

      data = response.text

    # credentials to get access google cloud storage
    # write your key path in place of gcloud_private_key.json
      storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/projects/xxx/secrets/bucketSecret/versions/1/xxx')

    # write your bucket name in place of bucket1go
      bucket_name = 'xxx'
      BUCKET = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
      # your object
      json_object = data
    # set the filename of your json object
      filename = "data_{}.json".format(today)

    # run the function and pass the json_object
      print(create_json(json_object, filename))
```

It's very clear that it has to do with some string but I cannot find any empty string in my code!

the requirements file

```
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
bs4==0.0.1
requests==2.28.2
google-cloud-storage==1.40.0
```

.gcloudignore file

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore
node_modules
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the deployment files. Cloud Functions does not use/support macOS. Are you using `pyenv`? Edit your question with the deploy command and requirements.txt.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok so it might be because of the user-agent in the header?!

Comment: I could be wrong, but... Can you see the files that have been uploaded to google cloud ? I'm thinking that maybe you are unsuspectedly uploading to Google Cloud more files from your computer (which... is it a Mac?) than you think. My theory (which could be totally wrong) is that you are uploading parts of your local environment to gcloud when you deploy your Gcloud function. To clarify: I don't think that error is coming from your Python code but earlier (from your deployment of the Glcoud function)

Comment: @BorrajaX it worked you were right it's because I uploaded the code in a ZIP file. I wrote the code instead of uploading it in a ZIP file.